# Задание начального фона для select multiple

Tags: html, select2

Когда загружается страничка, где есть `< select multiple >`, то в списке опций задается цвет по умолчанию (в хроме он `#c8c8c8`, в фаерфоксе синий). Как его задать/сделать прозрачным?

Пробовал через комбинации псевдоклассов и через `js` - все напрасно. При клике на опцию все работает, но до этого нет, [например](http://jsfiddle.net/w76gLox5/):

```html
<select multiple>
   <option selected>1111111</option>
   <option selected>222222222</option>
   <option selected>33333333</option>
   <option selected>44444444</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подсмотрел [здесь](https://www.speich.net/articles/en/2014/01/23/css-trick-setting-background-color-of-a-selected-html-option-element/). Мозилла заменяет только если использовать свойство `background-image`. В примере картинка вставлена в css, но вы можете прописать url-путь к ней. Работает и в Хроме.

```css
option:checked, option:hover {
    background: #488f8f url("data:image/gif;base64,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") repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="">
  <option>Photo archive</option><option>Photography</option>
  <option selected="">Birds</option><option>Wildlife</option>
</select>
```

Comment: а генерировать фон можно по этому адресу: http://www.patternify.com/

Comment: @lexxl в источнике есть ссылка на генератор кода из картинки. Но это необязательно, можно же url картинки прописать.

Comment: учитывая рабочий код, мало кто зайдёт в источник в поиске истины. кроме того, ваш источник может через минуту стать нерабочим сайтом.